# How do i set access for actions from diferrent controllers in Yii?

Tags: php, yii

This is my access rule :

```
public function accessRules() {
           return array(
                array('allow',
                    'controllers'=> array('Cont1', 'Cont2', 'Contt3'),
                    'actions'    =>  ??// I don't know what should I write here
                ),
                array('deny', // deny all users
                    'users' => array('*'),
                ),
            );
}
```

Lets suppose that:

- in **Cont1** I have function **cont1func1**, **cont1func2**
- in **Cont2** I have function **cont2func1**, **cont2func2**, **cont2func3**
- List in **Cont3** I have function **cont3func1**, **cont3func2**

I want to give access for user:

- **UserX** to **cont1** and function **cont1func1**
- **UserY** to **cont1** having function **cont1funct1**, **cont1func2** and to cont2 having function **cont2func1**, **cont2func2**, **cont2func3**
- **UserZ** to **cont1** all function and **cont3** all function

How can I do that ? How do I define my actions ? Thx

UPDATE:

```
public function accessRules() {



        $controllers = array(' '); $actions = array('index');

        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State1") == true){ 
            array_push($controllers, 'cont1','cont2');
            array_push($actions, 'cont1funct1', 'cont1funct2');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State2") == true){ 
            array_push($controllers, 'cont1');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State3") == true){ 
            array_push($controllers, 'cont1');
            array_push($actions, 'cont1funct3','cont1funct4','cont1funct5','cont1funct6');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State4") == true){
            array_push($controllers, 'cont1');
        } 
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State5") == true){ D
            array_push($controllers, 'cont1');
        }
        if (Yii::app()->user->getState("State1") == false  && Yii::app()->user->getState("State2") == false && Yii::app()->user->getState("State3") == false  && Yii::app()->user->getState("State4") == false  && Yii::app()->user->getState("State5") == false){
            return array(
                array('deny', // deny all users
                    'users' => array('*'),
                ),
            );
        }else{
            $controllers = array_unique($controllers); //remove duplicates
            $actions = array_unique($actions);//remove duplicates
            return array(
                array('allow',
                    'controllers'=> $controllers,
                    'actions'    => $actions 
                ),
                array('deny', // deny all users
                    'users' => array('*'),
                ),
            );
        }
    }
```

This is what I achieved yet. But I don't know what will happens when I am starting adding function from another controller . Can u help me with this ?

Comment: Where are you defining your access filter, is it on each controller or you want to define it in the main controller from which other controllers extend from

Comment: It is defined in the main controller, please check my post again and see what i achieved

Comment: am working on it, let me share something in a few.

Comment: is Yii::app()->user->getState("State1") equivalent to either (userx,usery and userz)

Comment: the only remaining part is to now define 'user' => array('userx') as per the respective controller and action they have access to

Comment: actually if i add to actions a function from controller 1 and a function from controller 2 it works. I believed that it will throw me an a error  or smth, but it works,l I simply add to the actions parameters all of the function from all of the controllers that i neeede

Answer (score 0):

Function `accessRules()` should be inside **every** controller. So something like this will be helpful:

```
public function accessRules() {
       return array(
            array('allow',
                'actions'=>  array("create", "update", ...),
                'users'=>array("@")
            ),
            array('deny', // deny all users
                'users' => array('*'),
            ),
        );
}
```

Comment: Please check my post again, I do some updates and I want to be set in the main controller not in every controller